# What is the name of this plant? and how do I take care of it?

Tags: identification, trees, houseplants, bonsai

I only just got this plant and would like to know its name, also is it some sort of a bonsai?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a healthy *Beaucarnea recurvata* commonly known as ponytail palm, and no, it's not a bonsai. These are slow growing plants - they do best in bright daylight, with some sunlight if possible. Favoured temperature is around 70 deg F, though they will tolerate quite low temperatures. The bulbous bit at the bottom of the plant stores water, but you should water when it needs it  to keep the plant in optimal condition. Further info here https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/ponytailpalm